# Different width and height of an element while inspecting my code

Tags: javascript, html, css

How come while inspecting my code, the same canvas.time element has different width and height at the same time?

[image: while inspecting my code]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sp0r1.png): [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` property of the canvas element refers to the width of the renderer for the canvas. It is not guaranteed to be the same size as the DOM element. For DOM sizing, use properties such as `clientWidth` or `offsetWidth`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements